# Get Firebase analytics collection enable status

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-analytics

For firebase analytics, we can enable/disable analytics collection by calling

```
- (void)setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled:(BOOL)analyticsCollectionEnabled
```

But how can we get the enable status of Firebase analytics? Is there a method like:

```
- (BOOL)isAnalyticsCollectionEnabled
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. Analytics are *enabled* by default, so you can perfectly track this yourself. From Firebase documentation:

> Sets whether analytics collection is enabled for this app on this device. This setting is persisted across app sessions. By default it is enabled.

But, if your code eventually loses track of the current state, you should probably set it *again* to the desired on/off status just to be extra sure ;-)